# How to fix "Composer Installation" error in windows server 2012?

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

**I am trying to install composer to use Laravel framework on windows server and while installation it gives me error.**
I think my network blocks downloading composer elements and how can I install composer without installer file or is there any offline installation package ?

[image]

Comment: Can you check if your PHP installed in your windows have the extension ```php_openssl``` and ```php_curl``` enabled.

Comment: yes its enabled

Comment: Check this article, they have the same issue and trace routing the URL may give you some hints : https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4142

Answer (score 0):

This problem has occurred for me, I have installed composer and uninstalled it, and installed it again so this problem occur...
I fixed it by deleting the Variable environment... Try this solution:

1. Right-click on your computer or (This pc) icon.
2. click (properties).
3. click (system properties) in the right sidebar
4. click (advanced) at the top
5. click (Environment Variables)
6. chose (127.0.0.1:8898) or URL that appears on the previous window of the **composer error**